Spring 4 calculated placeholders for annotations
I have an annotation, with a String attribute, and I want it to be calculated at runtime.
In the specific case I am talking about
@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "10000" )

According to other answers, see Spring @Scheduled annotation random delay, it is possible to calculate it, e.g. with
@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "#{new java.util.Random().nextInt(10000)}") 

However, in my installation this does not work. Spring refuses to start context, with the error: "Invalid initialDelayString value"
I am using Spring 4.1.2.
So my question is: what configuration allows Spring to calculate annotations? There is some minimum Spring version? or there is some particular dependency to include?

Why are you still using such an old, and no longer supported Spring version?

Because few customers pay for such an upgrade...

I'd say that customers who value the security of their business would..., not to mention legal compliance to ensure customer data is secure. Also, as a developer/supplier you also have your responsibility that your customers receive a safe and secure product, which means upgrading.

You need to upgrade your Spring framework version to at least 4.2 or later.

Can I ask how/where did you find this information? there is some doc about this?

Spring Framework 4.2 release notes which mention enhancements including the use of SpEL expressions in annotations.
